# Why does the compiler skip this method?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am attempting to provide my client with multiple ways for visiting permutations. I created the following code that executes `Action<T[]> output` at each visitation:

```
    public void Permute<T>(T[][] sets, Action<T[]> output)
    {
        Permute(sets, 0, new T[sets.Length], output);
    }

    private void Permute<T>(T[][] sets, int set, T[] permutation, Action<T[]> output)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sets[set].Length; ++i)
        {
            permutation[set] = sets[set][i];

            if (set < (sets.Length - 1))
                Permute(sets, set + 1, permutation, output);
            else
                output(permutation);
        }
    }
```

and it works so I moved on to the next way for visiting permutations which is to use `IEnumerable<int[]>` and `yield return` pattern. Here is my implementation:

```
    public IEnumerable<int[]> Permute(int[][] sets)
    {
       return  Permute(sets, 0, new int[sets.Length]); // <--skips this
    }

    private IEnumerable<int[]> Permute(int[][] sets, int set, int[] permutation)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sets[set].Length; ++i)
        {
            permutation[set] = sets[set][i];

            if (set < (sets.Length - 1))
                Permute(sets, set + 1, permutation);
            else
                yield return permutation;
        }
    }
```

but this does not work. The compiler skips past the indicated line of code without attempting to execute it.

Can someone please explain to me how to modify the presented code such that it enables a `IEnumerable<int[]>` and `yield return` pattern?

Here is the client code to test it with: (I am using nunit)

```
    [Test]
    public void PermuteThreeDifferentSetsUsingTheirIndexValues()
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var indexSets = new[]
                            {
                                new[] {0, 1, 2},
                                new[] {0, 1, 2},
                                new[] {0, 1, 2},
                            };

        var results = _generator.Permute(indexSets);

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            _permCounter++;
            Console.Write(result[0]);
            Console.Write(" ");
            Console.Write(result[1]);
            Console.Write(" ");
            Console.Write(result[2]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Permutation Visitor Elapsed Ticks: " + stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);

        Assert.AreEqual(27, _permCounter);
    }
```

My hunch is that the compiler is not happy that I am **not** using the return value from the recursion. However, it is only a hunch. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My guess is that it *does* work, it just doesn't look right in the debugger, because `yield` `return` creates a lazy execution of the `IEnumerable`.  Try calling `ToList` on your resulting IEnumerable to force execution, and see what happens.  See also http://brianreiter.org/2011/01/14/ienumerable-is-lazy-and-thats-cool/

Comment: I do not want to convert ToList because there may be a very large number of items and overflow RAM.

Comment: You only have to do that long enough to prove to yourself that it's really working. :)  You don't have to leave the ToList() there permanently.  Calling ToList() will allow you to view the entire iteration in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

That's how it's designed to work, and what plenty of code makes liberal use of: `IEnumerable<T>` implementations are allowed to be lazy. Your `Permute` doesn't do any work directly: it returns an object that once you start to iterate over it, starts to do some of the work, and only enough to determine the first of the results. When your loop then requests the next item, your function continues, but only until the point where it can determine the second result.

This is very useful in code such as `enumerable.Where(some predicate).First()`, because it avoids evaluating the predicate once the first result has been found.

In your outer-most function, you do iterate over the results of `_generator.Permute(indexSets)`, but inside that function, you call `Permute(sets, set + 1, permutation)` and discard the result (as you noted in the question). Since you do not use that recursive call's result, the effect is as if that recursive call never happens.

Generally speaking, when you want to recursively call yourself inside an iterator function, you need to `yield return` each of the results. A silly example:

```
IEnumerable<int> f(int n) {
    if (n > 0)
        foreach (var i in f(n - 1))
            yield return i;
    for (int i = 0; i != n; i++)
        yield return i;
}
```

Comment: Again - as I just commented to Mike - in my client code, I am iterating over the results using a foreach - isn't this supposed to enable the yield return?